# rsync command is taking too long each time

Tags: rsync, performance

For a long time I've been using rsync and a usb cable to get the photos from my phone's SD card onto the PC. This is the current command:

```
rsync -azvu --ignore-existing --progress SD-Karte/DCIM/Camera/  /home/cardamom/Pictures/PhonePictures/
```

It took me a while to get it right by trial and error and reading the docs. There are probably many thousand of photos in each directory but one would not think that it would take a computer that long to compare two lists a thousand long and if there is anything in the source which is not in the destination, bring it accross.

Yet, if I take a single extra photo with the phone, or even no extra photo, it will sit there for what feels like two or three minutes thinking and then transfer the one photo in about a second.

Am not sure if the bottleneck is in the rsync command which is doing something I don't need like comparing hashes of file, or if it is in the SD card of the old smartphone, which somehow has some big inefficiency.

Is there anything inefficient in the rsync command, or otherwise some kind of measure to make it go quicker inside the phone?

Comment: I would probably drop the `-z`, (along with `-v` and `--progress` ) but each sync will need to fetch info of 1000s on computer and 1000s on phone, that take time.

Comment: Can see that `-z` means 'compress' which sounds like a performance thing more than a functionality thing, will try without that now and see what happens.

Comment: compress might be usefull if you have a slow network connection.

Comment: Okay, with only the `-z` gone it is taking just as long. I think that both `-v` and `--progress` do much the same thing, ie tell you what it is doing. Since the slowness happens when almost nothing except 'sendng incremental file list' is printed, and the actual transferring, which is printed on the screen happens quickly, can't see how removing them would help. I think it's probably the SD card on the phone and there is not much you can do to speed this up but empty the photos folder out.

Comment: You can try to do just a `find /SD-Karte/DCIM/Camera -ls` and find out how long it takes. It is more or less what `rsync` has to do. If the find takes a long time, then the issue is your connection to the phone and it might be improved with other mount options, if you tell us how it is mounted now.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thanks I did `time find SD-Karte/DCIM/Camera -ls` and it took a while to dump 4610 files into the terminal, specifically `real 2m31,160s user m0,070s sys 0m0,132s`. So I suppose that clarifies where the bottleneck is. I believe it is mounted 'mtp'. It's a 2011 smartphone so not sure how many options it has..

Comment: If it's over `mtp` you need to add `--omit-dir-times` and `--no-perms` to your options. Can you do that and maybe put `--itemize` instead of `--progress`? That output will tell us just what `rsync` is trying to do.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani the final command looked like this : `time rsync -azvu --ignore-existing --itemize-changes --no-perms --omit-dir-times from/here/  /to/here/` the output and timing included `sent 14,834,457 bytes  received 208 bytes  93,594.10 bytes/sec total size is 6,718,187,545  speedup is 452.87 real 2m38,685s user 0m0,857s sys 0m0,138s` and ten new photos were brought accross, each line looked like this: `>f+++++++++ IMG_20200613_132428.jpg` Two and a half minutes for ten photos..

Comment: That's the normal output. You did not get any itemized line for the existing files then?

Comment: No, only for the files present in the phone but not yet in the PC..

Comment: my setup has Windows 10 on the sending side. I noticed that deactivating _Microsoft _Defender_'s real-time/always-on protection (_Antimalware Service Executable_ / `MsMpEng.exe`) temporarily significantly speeds up _rsync_'s file list gathering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it takes too long, it might be because `rsync` cannot apply its `quick check` that only relies on size and time.

Note that different filesystems store the time in different ways and that means that what  `rsync` stores is not always what it later retrieves.

When that happens, `rsync` cannot apply the quick check and turns to a checksum check, that forces it to read the whole file just to be sure it is the same one, thus slowing the whole transfer.

```
ls -l --time-style=full-iso original_file
ls -l --time-style=full-iso already_synced_file
```

Tells you if that is the case. If it is, you have at least two options, depending on how far off they are:

- Add `--size-only` option to just check the size and no the time.
- Use the `--modify-window` option to take that into account.

Comment: That is interesting, that modify-window thing and size-only, had never heard of them. I just did this: `rsync -azvu --size-only --dry-run --modify-window=120  from/here/  /to/here/`  Forgot to time it but it still took forever (ie two or three minutes) Will have a play with your ls commands and see what happens

Comment: But you forgot the `--omit-dir-times`and `--no-perms`. I also suggest build your flags the other way around, instead of starting with `-a` and removing things, I would start with just `size-only` and `v` and build from there. `-a` is meant mainly for the same (or similar) type of filesystem.

Comment: Ok, will try it, thanks. Did not know that order mattered..

Comment: Am playing with it, `time rsync --dry-run  --omit-dir-times --no-perms --size-only --modify-window=120   from/here/  /to/here/` seems not to be enough - it runs almost instantly telling me `skipping directory .` but it fails to transfer the one new photo. Will leave `--dry-run` in there till something is working, want to test it first before maybe wrecking any folders.

Comment: From the docs: `-a, --archive is is equivalent to -rlptgoD.`

Comment: I have something which works - will post answer seperately.

Answer (score 1):

So the following seems to make my photo syncing run really quickly - three seconds instead of three minutes. I got rid of the abbreviations so it is clear which is which:

```
time rsync --dry-run --verbose --compress --update --ignore-existing --recursive --group --times --progress --omit-dir-times --no-perms  --modify-window=120   from/here/  /to/here/
```

Get rid of time when no longer ned to time it, get rid of dry run when it seems to be doing what is meant to and is not harming anything.

Noticed as was building it there were quite a few accelerator and brake at the same time situations in the command and rsync never complained. For example, `-a` being `-rlptgoD` , the p is for `--perms` and for a while I also had `--no-perms` in there.

Will keep observing the dry runs for a while and make sure it continues to behave.

Comment: If your SD card is FAT you must use modify-window=2 as per the man page

Comment: Thanks, just checked it with `df -Th` and it's not, it's ext4. There's a few others in there like tempfs and squashfs but no FAT.

Comment: There's no point using `--compress` - in fact you're potentially slowing down the transfer. It's only of use when copying across a network.